# VMWare Workstation 11.1 unable to start services on 15.04

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

error log file

```
015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Log for VMware Workstation pid=19545 version=11.1.0 build=build-2496824 option=Release
2015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: The process is 64-bit.
2015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Host codepage=UTF-8 encoding=UTF-8
2015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Host is Linux 3.19.0-18-generic Ubuntu 15.04
2015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Msg_Reset:
2015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/usr/lib/vmware/settings": No such file or directory.
2015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: ----------------------------------------
2015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /usr/lib/vmware/settings. Using default values.
2015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Msg_Reset:
2015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/config": No such file or directory.
2015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: ----------------------------------------
2015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: PREF Optional preferences file not found at /root/.vmware/config. Using default values.
2015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: PREF Unable to check permissions for preferences file.
2015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: DictionaryLoad: Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Msg_Reset:
2015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: [msg.dictionary.load.openFailed] Cannot open file "/root/.vmware/preferences": No such file or directory.
2015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: ----------------------------------------
2015-05-27T20:52:48.807+05:30| vthread-4| I120: PREF Failed to load user preferences.
2015-05-27T20:52:48.864+05:30| vthread-4| W110: Logging to /tmp/vmware-root/vmware-19545.log
2015-05-27T20:52:48.883+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2015-05-27T20:52:48.883+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Created new pathsHash.
2015-05-27T20:52:48.883+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Setting header path for 3.19.0-18-generic to "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include".
2015-05-27T20:52:48.883+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:52:48.883+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-05-27T20:52:48.883+05:30| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-05-27T20:52:48.883+05:30| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 for preprocess check
2015-05-27T20:52:48.892+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:52:48.892+05:30| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.19.0-18-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-05-27T20:52:49.067+05:30| vthread-4| I120: found symbol version file /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/Module.symvers
2015-05-27T20:52:49.067+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.091+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Read 18826 symbol versions
2015-05-27T20:52:49.091+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vmmon module.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.091+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vmnet module.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.091+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vmblock module.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.091+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vmci module.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.091+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Reading in info for the vsock module.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.091+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Setting vsock to depend on vmci.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.091+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmmon".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.095+05:30| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.095+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.098+05:30| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.098+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmblock".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.101+05:30| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.101+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmci".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.104+05:30| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.104+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vsock".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.107+05:30| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 0.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.127+05:30| vthread-4| I120: to be installed: vmnet status: 0
2015-05-27T20:52:49.143+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.143+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Setting header path for 3.19.0-18-generic to "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.143+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.143+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-05-27T20:52:49.143+05:30| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.143+05:30| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 for preprocess check
2015-05-27T20:52:49.152+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.152+05:30| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.19.0-18-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-05-27T20:52:49.326+05:30| vthread-4| I120: found symbol version file /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/Module.symvers
2015-05-27T20:52:49.326+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.350+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Read 18826 symbol versions
2015-05-27T20:52:49.350+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Kernel header path retrieved from FileEntry: /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include
2015-05-27T20:52:49.350+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Update kernel header path to /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include
2015-05-27T20:52:49.350+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.350+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-05-27T20:52:49.350+05:30| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.350+05:30| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 for preprocess check
2015-05-27T20:52:49.360+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.360+05:30| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.19.0-18-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-05-27T20:52:49.361+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Found compiler at "/usr/bin/gcc"
2015-05-27T20:52:49.365+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Got gcc version "4.9.2".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.365+05:30| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.365+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Using user supplied compiler "/usr/bin/gcc".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.369+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Got gcc version "4.9.2".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.369+05:30| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.375+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Trying to find a suitable PBM set for kernel "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.375+05:30| vthread-4| I120: No matching PBM set was found for kernel "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.376+05:30| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.376+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.376+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-05-27T20:52:49.376+05:30| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.376+05:30| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 for preprocess check
2015-05-27T20:52:49.384+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.384+05:30| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.19.0-18-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-05-27T20:52:49.386+05:30| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.386+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.387+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-05-27T20:52:49.387+05:30| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.387+05:30| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 for preprocess check
2015-05-27T20:52:49.397+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.397+05:30| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.19.0-18-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-05-27T20:52:49.398+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.399+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.399+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Setting header path for 3.19.0-18-generic to "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.399+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.399+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-05-27T20:52:49.399+05:30| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.399+05:30| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 for preprocess check
2015-05-27T20:52:49.409+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.409+05:30| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.19.0-18-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-05-27T20:52:49.579+05:30| vthread-4| I120: found symbol version file /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/Module.symvers
2015-05-27T20:52:49.579+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2015-05-27T20:52:49.602+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Read 18826 symbol versions
2015-05-27T20:52:49.603+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2015-05-27T20:52:49.606+05:30| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2015-05-27T20:52:50.389+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2015-05-27T20:52:50.389+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2015-05-27T20:52:50.400+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2015-05-27T20:52:50.401+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-nhXp44/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2015-05-27T20:52:52.605+05:30| vthread-4| W110: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
2015-05-27T20:57:07.473+05:30| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2015-05-27T20:57:07.474+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:57:07.474+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-05-27T20:57:07.474+05:30| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-05-27T20:57:07.474+05:30| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 for preprocess check
2015-05-27T20:57:07.486+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:57:07.486+05:30| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.19.0-18-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-05-27T20:57:07.486+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2015-05-27T20:57:07.487+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2015-05-27T20:57:07.488+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Setting header path for 3.19.0-18-generic to "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include".
2015-05-27T20:57:07.488+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:57:07.488+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-05-27T20:57:07.488+05:30| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-05-27T20:57:07.488+05:30| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 for preprocess check
2015-05-27T20:57:07.499+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:57:07.499+05:30| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.19.0-18-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-05-27T20:57:07.673+05:30| vthread-4| I120: found symbol version file /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/Module.symvers
2015-05-27T20:57:07.674+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2015-05-27T20:57:07.698+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Read 18826 symbol versions
2015-05-27T20:57:07.698+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2015-05-27T20:57:07.702+05:30| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2015-05-27T20:57:08.434+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2015-05-27T20:57:08.435+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2015-05-27T20:57:08.445+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2015-05-27T20:57:08.445+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-msV3BN/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2015-05-27T20:57:10.564+05:30| vthread-4| W110: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
2015-05-27T20:57:28.418+05:30| vthread-4| I120: The GCC version matches the kernel GCC minor version like a glove.
2015-05-27T20:57:28.418+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:57:28.418+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-05-27T20:57:28.418+05:30| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-05-27T20:57:28.418+05:30| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 for preprocess check
2015-05-27T20:57:28.431+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:57:28.431+05:30| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.19.0-18-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-05-27T20:57:28.431+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Using temp dir "/tmp".
2015-05-27T20:57:28.432+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Obtaining info using the running kernel.
2015-05-27T20:57:28.433+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Setting header path for 3.19.0-18-generic to "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include".
2015-05-27T20:57:28.433+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Validating path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for kernel release "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:57:28.433+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Failed to find /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h
2015-05-27T20:57:28.433+05:30| vthread-4| I120: /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include/linux/version.h not found, looking for generated/uapi/linux/version.h instead.
2015-05-27T20:57:28.433+05:30| vthread-4| I120: using /usr/bin/gcc-4.9 for preprocess check
2015-05-27T20:57:28.444+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Preprocessed UTS_RELEASE, got value "3.19.0-18-generic".
2015-05-27T20:57:28.444+05:30| vthread-4| I120: The header path "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include" for the kernel "3.19.0-18-generic" is valid.  Whoohoo!
2015-05-27T20:57:28.623+05:30| vthread-4| I120: found symbol version file /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/Module.symvers
2015-05-27T20:57:28.623+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Reading symbol versions from /lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/Module.symvers.
2015-05-27T20:57:28.648+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Read 18826 symbol versions
2015-05-27T20:57:28.648+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Invoking modinfo on "vmnet".
2015-05-27T20:57:28.653+05:30| vthread-4| I120: "/sbin/modinfo" exited with status 256.
2015-05-27T20:57:30.414+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Setting destination path for vmnet to "/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/misc/vmnet.ko".
2015-05-27T20:57:30.415+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Extracting the vmnet source from "/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet.tar".
2015-05-27T20:57:30.426+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Successfully extracted the vmnet source.
2015-05-27T20:57:30.426+05:30| vthread-4| I120: Building module with command "/usr/bin/make -j4 -C /tmp/modconfig-EZo7Ql/vmnet-only auto-build HEADER_DIR=/lib/modules/3.19.0-18-generic/build/include CC=/usr/bin/gcc IS_GCC_3=no"
2015-05-27T20:57:33.579+05:30| vthread-4| W110: Failed to build vmnet.  Failed to execute the build command.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am on 14.10 64-bit. Kernel 3.19. The following steps worked for me under VMware Worstation 11 and VMware Player 7.1.0: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VMware#3.19_kernels

Answer (score -2):

```
curl http://pastie.org/pastes/9934018/download -o /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch

cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar -xf vmnet.tar
patch -p0 -i /tmp/vmnet-3.19.patch
mv vmnet.tar vmnet.tar.SAVED
tar -cf vmnet.tar vmnet-only
rm -r vmnet-only
vmware-modconfig --console --install-all
```

Comment: Some context here would be nice please see http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer